# How do I disable Cmd-D in Terminal?

Tags: terminal, keyboard

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> splits the terminal screen horizontally.
How do I disable this "feature"?
(Every time I accidentally this key, I have to undo it using <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> and then re-maximize the window).

This [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/28112/60079) offers a command line which does not seem to change anything on OS X 10.11.6 (15G1004). Also, I would like a "permanent solution" - do I add the command to the `.bashrc`? `.profile`?

People also recommend iTerm2 - I do *not* want to install anything, I am quite happy with `tmux` on top of the regular terminal - except for this stupid problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Rebind the shortcut in keyboard preferences in system preferences?

Comment: @JohnKeates: I tried. I can't find the place where the key is bound to something in terminal. I guess I can create a global binding for it, but I will need something completely harmless because I often hit cmd-d instead of alt-d.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assign a different key combination to `Terminal`’s `Split Pane` menu item:

1. Quit `Terminal`
2. Open `System Preferences`
3. Select the panel `Keyboard` from the second row
4. Select the tab `Shortcuts` at top center
5. Select `App Shortcuts` from the bottom of the list on the left
6. Click the `+` button, bottom center and a smaller panel appears
7. In the dropdown menu `Application:`, select `Terminal`

   1. if Terminal isn’t on the list, scroll all the way to the bottom and select `Other…` (otherwise, skip to step 8 below)
   2. when a dialog window appears, go to the folder `Utilities` and select `Terminal`
8. In the `Menu Title:` field, enter the text “`Split Pane`” without quotation marks, but with capital letters “S” and “P”
9. In the `Keyboard Shortcut:` field, enter your custom key combination
   Pro tips:

   1. for a feature you hate, select a key combination you’ll never enter on accident, such as <kbd>command ⌘</kbd>‑<kbd>control ⌃</kbd>‑<kbd>option ⌥</kbd>‑<kbd>shift ⇧</kbd>‑<kbd>D</kbd>
   2. select and hold down the modifier keys (that is, <kbd>command ⌘</kbd>, <kbd>control ⌃</kbd>, <kbd>option ⌥</kbd>, and <kbd>shift ⇧</kbd>) *before* you select the letter key (in this example, <kbd>D</kbd>)
10. Click `Add`
11. Restart your Mac and fire up `Terminal`
12. Become less unhappy

Comment: It's not necessary to quit Terminal in order to make this change.

Answer (score 8):

Copy and paste into the terminal:

```
defaults write com.apple.Terminal NSUserKeyEquivalents '{"Split Pane" = "@~^$d";}'
```

This is equivalent to the GUI step-by-step instructions in the accepted answer.

Alas, those steps have to be done after every OS update, so a command line approach is a good idea.